# Blank Access Instance Persists after Returning Recordset

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm using Excel to open an instance of access and return a recordset. Not sure why, but after the code executes a blank instance of Access opens up. I can't even close it without opening up task manager.

The actual methods are slightly more complex than this, but for simplicity here is my code in Excel:

```
Private Function t()

    Dim ac As Access.Application
    Set ac = New Access.Application
    Dim rs As DAO.recordSet

    ac.OpenCurrentDatabase (dataLocation)
    Set rs = ac.Run("Test2")

    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        Call writeRecordSet(rs, sht, 1, 1)
    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    ac.CloseCurrentDatabase
    ac.Quit

    Set ac = Nothing

End Function
```

Access code:

```
Public Function test2() As DAO.Recordset

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_Aero_Units")
    Set test2 = rs

End Function
```

I think it has to do with the recordset object not being closed because it only happens once I write it to the Excel sheet. Anyone know why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

UPDATE: After the function is complete I can hit the reset button and closes the instance of Access.

Comment: So I made the db visible. It looks like on the closecurrentdatabase Access goes to the load screen as if you opened access with no specific database. Then on the .quit it closes that screen to the blank access instance, but doesn't close the application. Am I missing a line to close the instance?

Comment: That's the database location, opencurrentdatabase needs a database as an argument

Comment: I thought I was closing the database then quitting the application. Either way I've tried it with only the close line and only the quit line. Same result... Weird right?

Comment: That makes sense.  I realized that, and edited the comment. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68976/discussion-between-peege-and-fortedevelop).

Comment: Does your writeRecordSet function pass the recordset variable byRef or byVal?  If it's byRef, then that may be holding the Access application open until it falls out of scope.

Comment: Do you really need to run the Access VBA. If you just want the recordset, you can use `ac.CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT ....")` Right now, the table gets locked, altering Access' behavior on close down